# What is the order of operations with this concatenation?

Tags: ruby, string, symbols, operator-precedence

```
x = "hello" " world".to_sym
puts x.class
```

This works and allows me to concatenate the two strings into a symbol, producing the output:

```
Symbol
```

But if I change it slightly to use a + instead of a space separating the hello and world strings, I get an error:

```
x = "hello" + " world".to_sym
puts x.class
```

This produces the following error - I think this is because it's trying to 'cast' the "world".to_sym call back to a string before concatenating it onto the "hello" string:

```
in `+': can't convert Symbol into String (TypeError)
```

I'm wondering **what makes the first example work**? Does anyone know what the order of operations is here? I suspect the two strings are actually treated as one, that the space between them is ignored and they are concatenated before the to_sym method is called. I actually would have expected it to work no differently than the second example because I thought the to_sym would be called on the "world" string BEFORE any attempt is made to join the contents of "hello" and "world".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two or more string **literals** put right beside each other like that are immediately treated as a single string literal. When the Ruby interpreter converts your code to tokens, it converts

```
"hello" " world"
```

to the single token `string "hello world"` and it converts

```
"hello" + " world"
```

to three tokens: `string "hello"`, `method +`, and `string " world"`. It would then concatenate the strings together later on when actually executing the code.

Answer (score 4):

The first example is syntactic sugar, normally you see this written like:

```
x = "Here is a string that " \
    "I want to split across " \
    "several lines..."
```

So this happens first, before `to_sym`. In the second example you are literally calling:

```
x = "hello".+( "world".to_sym )
```

Which is obviously not going to work since `String#+` can't do anything useful with a symbol as an argument.

In short, don't do the first one, if you want to do `"hello world".to_sym` and you can't just write it like that for whatever reason then just use parenthesis: `("hello" + " world").to_sym`